# How to send notification to multiple sns topics at once

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have 9000 AWS SNS topics with more than 1M subscribers in each topic. At the moment I am lopping to each topic to send a push message which is consuming lot of my system resources. Is there a way to send message to all the topics at once? what is the best approach to handle the scenario?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to subscribe Amazon SNS queues to an Amazon SNS queue, so there is no out-of-the-box method for sending one message to multiple queues.

I would recommend creating an **AWS Lambda function** that will:

- **Retrieve a list** of all relevant queues (based on tag?)
- Loops through and **sends a message to each queue**

Thus, you would just trigger the Lambda function with one message and it would go to all other queues. It would not "consume system resources", but it is **charged based upon run duration**. Lambda functions can run for a maximum of 15 minutes, so as long as it sends 10+ messages per minute, it can send to 9000 topics.

Depending upon your use-case, you might also consider using [Amazon Pinpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/welcome.html):

> **Amazon Pinpoint** is an AWS service that you can use to engage with your customers across multiple messaging channels. You can use Amazon Pinpoint to send push notifications, emails, SMS text messages, and voice messages.